# CORS issue while sending POST request to Laravel API from React app

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, api, cors

I am currently building a React application that sends POST requests to a Laravel backend API. I have enabled CORS in Laravel and I am able to successfully send requests from Postman. However, when I try to send the same request from my React application, I get an error 201.

I have tried several things to debug the problem including:

Ensuring that my Laravel CORS middleware is correctly implemented.
Adding the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to my Laravel responses.
Adding the "credentials: include" option to my fetch request in the React application